# How do I use manual focus on my Canon PowerShot SX210 IS?

Tags: canon, manual-focus

When I turn to manual focus setting in the camera, a bar appears on the right side of the screen which has measurements like ***1 2 5 m***. Increasing on decreasing that bar doesn't show any effects on the screen.

I haphazardly maximized the focus to infinite symbol for a macro shot. This resulted in a NOT so sharp image.

What is the way to use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the user manual, you first focus approximately using the screen and distance bar, then press the shutter button halfway to enable you to fine tune the focus. You need to be in M, Av, Tv or P mode.

If you are trying to focus on something close, the last thing you want to do is focus to infinity!

Comment: Thanks, distance bar tells us the distance between the subject and the camera?

Comment: Yes, though I'm not sure how accurate it is in that particular camera's case.

Comment: Thanks, so the distance bar tells me that the distance between the camera and the subject is 20cm. How am I supposed to use that information? Sorry for the dumb question, but I need to know this.

Comment: I doubt that the distance scale is in cm, it's more likely that it's in meters. This maybe explains why you were seeing no difference on-screen when you were focusing. You can use the distance scale to get into the right 'neighbourhood' for focusing so you can then fine tune it easier. You could also use it very approximately for hyper-focal distance measurement, but that's an entirely different and more advanced kettle of fish.

Comment: The distance was in cm, the object was on the table, so was the camera, the maximum scale that gets shown is 1m. What did you mean by _"right 'neighbourhood' "_? I couldn't understand that.

Comment: I mean the distance scale is just there as a rough guide, the ultimate decider is if it looks in focus on the screen.